# Duvida Como Recuperar Dados no formato blob e exibir em jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, blob

Bom Pessoal estou com uma duvida bem critica eu não estou conseguindo recuperar os dados de um campo do meu banco de dados que possui o formato blob li algumas documentações porem não consegui entender muito gostaria de saber se alguem pode me dar uma dica ou ate mesmo algum exemplo para que eu possa me direcionar, estou usando mysql como banco de dados.

Comment: Você sabe qual o tipo de informação que foi armazenada (imagem, video, audio...)?

Comment: sei sim foi armazenado texto e imagem

Comment: texto e imagem em apenas um campo BLOB ou apenas a imagem está no campo BLOB?

Comment: texto e imagem em apenas um campo BLOB

Comment: Cara, complicado. Porque um campo blob é apenas um array de byte e para convertê-lo de volta é preciso saber o tipo. Se for apenas imagem, basta montá-lo em um objeto nativo Java. Mas sendo dois valores em apenas um blob só consigo imaginar a criação de uma classe com dois atributos de tipos diferentes (String, File) para serializá-lo e só depois mandar para um blob e lê-lo de volta. Sendo assim, você precisa saber de que forma foi armazenado EXATAMENTE para fazer o processo de leitura.

Comment: putz é por que não foi eu quem montou essa estrutura so o que sei da estrutura e que o campo é array de bytes